# How to handle avatar upload in REST manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have User model, where user should be able to upload one picture as an avatar. But I don't really know how to implement this in correct REST way. I see two options

First I think of avatar as of member resource that belongs to user, so I add two actions to my **Users Controller**, one **avatar** for the upload form, and second action for handling the actual upload **avatar_upadte**, so my routes look like

```
map.resources :users, :member => { :avatar => :get, :avatar_update => :post }
```

Second I can think of avatar as of separate resource and create **Avatars Controller** instead, which would be like

```
map.resources :users
map.resources :avatars, :only => [ :new, :create ]
```

**I don't want to handle avatar upload in `edit_user` action, since it is already pretty complex.**

The third option could be to have only **avatar** action to display the form and then user REST user update action as upload target, where form would be something like this

```
<% form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :avatar, 'Avatar' %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <%= f.submit 'Upload' %>
<% end %>
```

But I don't like this this attitude either, because since my update action already handles another form, it would be pretty ugly to handle redirects etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the app I work on we do something like this:

```
map.resources :users do |u|
    u.resources :avatars # You can also make this a singleton resource
end
```

This gives you a route like:  `/users/1/avatars/new`

This might not make sense for your app, if not I would choose the option of having a separate AvatarsController.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

- Option 1 adds a custom action to the User resource, which is best avoided if at all possible.
- Option 2 splits User and Avatar into separate resources, but doesn't make it easy to connect the two (for example, when creating an upload form).
- Option 3 looks like you'd view the Avatar as a User attribute.

The most important thing to figure out at this point is: what's the cardinality of the relationship between User and Avatar. Does a User have one Avatar or many? If there's a one-to-many relationship, then a solution like the one Jonnii proposes might make sense.

If a User will only have one Avatar (which seems likely), I would consider going with the simplest solution and make the Avatar a User attribute.

Although I haven't gotten around to trying it out, I've heard good things about [Paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/tree/master). The example usages even discuss using Paperclip with avatars.

For an even more lightweight solution, you might consider [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/), which would eliminate the need for a file upload entirely and simplify things a lot.

Comment: actualy, I'm using paperclip, so avatar works as an attribute of User model, but since it is already quite complex, I don't want to put it to the same edit action.